# How can I tell if a QtMainWindow is being resized?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I don't want to know *after* the fact (for that, I could just catch the resizeEvent), I would like to know *before* anything has actually happened, when the user has clicked on a side/corner and has started dragging things around, and then again when the mouse has been released after the resize has finished.  (I know I can catch the mouse events, but is there someway to tell that these events will cause the window to resize?)

Comment: Those events are usually handled by the window manager, then you won't be told before the resize actually happens.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd accept this as the answer, except that it seems to be a comment.  Or maybe I'm just not seeing where the green checkmark is supposed to appear.